# Convolution of measures on a measurable group is associative

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

I've come across a statement in Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability* which claims this and only tells me to use Fubini's theorem. I am not very familiar with this topic and the text doesn't give any further detail, so I have several questions here:

1. Do the measures need to be at least $\sigma$-finite (since the author tells me to use Fubini's)?
2. Does the actual proof resemble this:

$$ \begin{align} ((\mu_1 * \mu_2) * \mu_3)(B) &= \iint \chi_B(xz) (\mu_1*\mu_2)(dx) \mu_3(dz) \\ &= \iiint \chi_B(xyz) \mu_1(dx) \mu_2(dy) \mu_3(dz) \\ &= \iiint \chi_B(xyz) \mu_2(dy) \mu_3(dz) \mu_1(dx) \\ &= \iint \chi_B(xy) (\mu_2*\mu_3)(dy) \mu_1(dx) \\ &= \iint \chi_B(xy) (\mu_2*\mu_3)(dy) \mu_1(dx) \\& = \iint \chi_B(xy) \mu_1(dx)  (\mu_2*\mu_3)(dy) = (\mu_1 * (\mu_2 * \mu_3))(B) \end{align}$$

in which case it doesn't assume that the $\mu_i$ are invariant under the group operations at all. On the other hand, the answers in [Convolution on group with measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/convolution-on-group-with-measure) claim that they need to be so, so am I misunderstanding this somehow?